# Where to report issues of the jira.codehaus.org bug tracker itself?

Tags: jira, bug-tracker

I searched through the project list and don't seem to find a good candidate. The link "Report a bug" on the buttom of the page which looks like it serves to report issues of the site does the same thing a the "Create" button for new issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following the advise within the Introduction section which is:

> email support at codehaus.org (if your issue is with JIRA)